# Connections from Apache to Tomcat using proxypass are not closed after each request

Tags: apache, tomcat

I currently have apache2 configured so that requests on specific urls such as /myapp are directed to my internal tomcat server at tomcathost:8080/myapp.

All the requests to myapp to apache2 work as expected.

The problem that I'm facing is that whenever a request is sent to myapp trough apache2 it seems that apache2 is keeping the connection open to tomcat and after a while all the threads in tomcat are taken by apache and apparently not released.

Could somebody point me in the right direction to solve this issue ?

```
ProxyPass /myapp balancer://apps/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp balancer://apps/myapp

<Proxy balancer://apps>
 BalancerMember http://appserver01:8080 route=Node01 loadfactor=1
 BalancerMember http://appserver02:8080 route=Node02 loadfactor=1
 ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
 ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
 ProxySet nofailover=On
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set connectiontime out in server.xml so incase if any thread is open it get timedout.

```
connectionTimeout="120000"
```

Also you might use JConsole which is part of JDK installation to monitor threads via JMX for your tomcat to see if there is any loop of threads which causes increase in threads.